# Get records between two dates from a DB table without a timestamp column incrementally

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I am having a table a which don't have timestamp column:
its having data like:

```
 name     city
------  ------
 Deepak  Pune
 amit    Mumbai
 raj     Chennai
```

now on a next day, we have below data:

```
    name    city
   -----  ------  
   Deepak  Chennai
   amit    Mumbai
   raj     Chennai 
   vikas   Panjab
```

now  I want to find those records which are modified or inserted or deleted.

for ex: 
        name    city
       -----  ------
       Deepak  Chennai (updated from pune to Chennai)
       amit    Mumbai
       raj     Chennai 
       vikas   Panjab   (Inserted new record)

but I don't want to compare as table has many columns because there are many columns and billion records. 
that's why I want to pick records between two timstamp, So I come to know which are modified.

So O/P:

```
name  City
---- ------
Deepak Chennai
vikas  Panjab
```

Please suggest what I need to use..

Comment: *"So I come to know which are modified."* Without details of when the row was inserted or updated..? You don't. Without storing that meta data you can't get that information. Much like if you were asked "Can you find out how many of our customers have blue eyes?" but that isn't a piece of data you store.

Comment: Which database are you using? You've tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`.

Comment: Hi if you have on sql server 2016 or newer you can take look at the temporal table https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your requirements.You have one table  like `users` with data

```
Name Null? Type         
---- ----- ------------ 
NAME       VARCHAR2(10) 
CITY       VARCHAR2(10)



NAME    CITY
----    -----
raj     chennai
deepak  pune
amit    mubai
vikas   punjab
```

you can use this . it may help you.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT u.*,ROWNUM FROM users u ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

The result will be like this

```
 NAME     CITY   ROWNUM
 -----    -----  -----
 vikas    punjab   4
```